# Is there a built in report to list all items of one type that link to items of another type?

Tags: content-editor, content-management

I'm hoping there is a report of all pages that utilize items of a certain type (created from one template). I'm probably not asking this right, but here goes: I have a number of items created from several templates (single & double column page layouts basically). A number of them have a Blog Carousel at the bottom of the page, some do not. There are hundreds of these pages. There is a single folder with all the blog carousels.

Is there an easy way within the Content Editor to show all the "page" items that link to a any of the blog carousel items? NB: this is a many-to-one relationship (if that helps). In other words a single blog carousel can be used on multiple pages, but a page can only link to one single blog carousel.

(NB: very proficient in SQL - so if I have to go to the db to query the list that works for me as well - just need to know the join relationships.)

Comment: You may find the #spe channel on Slack to be helpful. Sitecore PowerShell Extensions comes with reports. For your requirement you may need to author a new report to handle the specific filtering you list.

Comment: You can consider using the "Links" button in the ribbon that allows you to find all the items that refer to the selected item.

Answer (score 3):

There are no OOTB reports with component/item usage, although if you have [Sitecore PowerShell Extensions](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/) installed it is fairly straight forward to generate one for your specific purpose.

You can however look up the usage of any specific item using the Links button from the Navigate ribbon. This will give you both a list of other items that refer to this item, and any other items that this item refers to.

[image: Item Links]

You can check this on any type of item in Sitecore (page item, datasource item, media item, template, layout, renderings etc).

If you do not see any links, ensure the Links database has been rebuilt from the Control Panel.